# How to use the new MediaSession class to receive media button presses on Android 5.x?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I’m attempting to receive media button presses using the new MediaSession class and so far I’ve been unsuccessful.  Has anyone managed to receive them using the new class?

I’ve been successful in creating a MediaSession and using it to update song information on a remote display (an in-car entertainment system) but so far I’m unable to receive button presses from it, headphone controls, and controls on Bluetooth headsets.

After I create the media session I’m executing the following in a service that I use to play audio:

```
    _mediaSession = new MediaSession(getApplicationContext(), Global.PACKAGE_NAME + "." + TAG);

    if (_mediaSession == null) {
        _log.e(TAG, "initMediaSession: _mediaSession = null");
        return;
    }

    _mediaSessionToken = _mediaSession.getSessionToken();

    _mediaSession.setCallback(new Callback() {
        public boolean onMediaButtonEvent(Intent mediaButtonIntent) {
            _log.d(TAG, "onMediaButtonEvent called: " + mediaButtonIntent);             
            return false;
        }

        public void onPause() {
            Log.d(TAG, "onPause called (media button pressed)");                
            super.onPause();
        }

        public void onPlay() {
            Log.d(TAG, "onPlay called (media button pressed)");             
            super.onPlay();
        }

        public void onStop() {
            Log.d(TAG, "onStop called (media button pressed)");             
            super.onStop();
        }
    });             

     _mediaSession.setFlags(MediaSession.FLAG_HANDLES_MEDIA_BUTTONS | MediaSession.FLAG_HANDLES_TRANSPORT_CONTROLS);

    PlaybackState state = new PlaybackState.Builder()
    .setActions(PlaybackState.ACTION_PLAY)
    .setState(PlaybackState.STATE_STOPPED, PlaybackState.PLAYBACK_POSITION_UNKNOWN, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime())
    .build();

    _mediaSession.setPlaybackState(state);

    _mediaSession.setActive(true);
```

but I’m still not receiving any button presses.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

**Update** After changing

```
    PlaybackState state = new PlaybackState.Builder()
    .setActions(PlaybackState.ACTION_PLAY)
    .setState(PlaybackState.STATE_STOPPED, PlaybackState.PLAYBACK_POSITION_UNKNOWN, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime())
    .build();
```

to

```
    PlaybackState state = new PlaybackState.Builder()
    .setActions(PlaybackState.ACTION_PLAY)
    .setState(PlaybackState.STATE_STOPPED, PlaybackState.PLAYBACK_POSITION_UNKNOWN, 0)
    .build();
```

I'm now receiving button press notifications via the onMediaButtonEvent() callback (such as being notified that KEYCODE_MEDIA_PAUSE was pressed) but onPlay(), onPause(), and onStop() are never being called, any idea why?

Comment: I don't know if this works for you, but you could try to add more supported actions to the `PlaybackState` instance, so replace: `.setActions(PlaybackState.ACTION_PLAY)` with: `.setActions(PlaybackState.ACTION_PLAY | PlaybackState.ACTION_PLAY_PAUSE | PlaybackState.ACTION_PAUSE );`

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I gave it a try and unfortunately adding the additional actions had no effect.

Comment: can you post more code..which gives us idea of when you are creating the media session and when you are initializing

Comment: The last parameter in the `.setState(...)` call should be the playback speed, I use 1 all the time, and it works for me. In my code I have `.setState(newState, 0, 1);` where `newState` is an integer computed as appropriate.

Comment: @ana01 Thanks, I change the playback speed to 1.  I'm now receiving button press notifications but only via the onMediaButtonEvent() callback, for some reason onPlay(), onPause(), onStop() is never being called even when onMediaButtonEvent() is called with KEYCODE_MEDIA_PAUSE.

Comment: @Aun I added additional code that I'm executing prior to calling setCallback() which creates the media session.  The above code is called after my player service starts (it's job is to play audio for the app).  In reality the code after the calls to setFlags() won't be called here (in my initialization function) but will instead be called elsewhere in the service.

Comment: @Gordon, I think that actually happens to me, too, but in my implementation I didn't use that callback anyway (I rely on the key codes only, because they're reported by the hardware buttons on the headset, too) and I don't have any idea why.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`onMediaButtonEvent(..)` has a default implementation in MediaSession.Callback. In your code if you call super.onMediaButtonEvent(..), then depending on the keycodes the correct callback namely `onPlay()`, `onPause()` will be called.

You can take a look at the default implementation in [MediaSession.java](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/media/java/android/media/session/MediaSession.java)

Comment: The MediaSessonCompat onMediaButtonEvent now has a check `android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 27 ` if true it the method returns false instantly without any further actions, because of that, the Bluetooth play/pause button is reaching until onMediaButtonEvent and does nothing after that.

Answer (score 3):

The default implementation of onMediaButtonEvent is what figures out the specific callback for a given media key event. Since you're overriding onMediaButtonEvent and not calling the super's implementation you will only get onPlay/Pause/etc. calls from other apps that are using a MediaController to make those calls directly.

If you add change your implementation to

```
public boolean onMediaButtonEvent(Intent mediaButtonIntent) {
    _log.d(TAG, "onMediaButtonEvent called: " + mediaButtonIntent);             
    return super.onMediaButtonEvent(mediaButtonIntent);
}
```

You should start seeing the keys translated to the other callback methods.