# Android MediaSession not reacting to headphones

Tags: android, android-mediasession

I'm quite new to android and I'm creating a Music Player.
I wasn't familiar with MediaSession and now I have a functioning Music Player but it does not support reacting to headphones clicks or pausing on incomming calls.

This is my code:

```
    ComponentName mediaButtonReceiver = new ComponentName(context, MusicPlayerNotificationReceiver.class);
    final MediaSessionCompat mediaSession = new MediaSessionCompat(context, "Start MP", mediaButtonReceiver, null);
    mediaSession.setFlags(MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_MEDIA_BUTTONS | MediaSessionCompat.FLAG_HANDLES_TRANSPORT_CONTROLS);
    LockerActivity.getInstance().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mediaSession.setCallback(MusicPlayer.this);
        }
    });
    mediaSession.setActive(true);
```

I also have a `BroadcastReceiver` that is defined with this action

`<action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />`

This is all of my code ralated to `MediaSession`.
So, for now, i just try to get notified for an action from the headphones. I have a breakpoint on the first line inside `onReceive()` and i click on the button in headphones and nothing happens. If i long click on the button than android goes into Listening mode for speak instructions.

What else do i need?

Comment: Try creating an explicit broadcast `PendingIntent` for the `MusicPlayerNotificationReceiver` class, and pass it as the fourth parameter in the `MediaSessionCompat` constructor.

Comment: @MikeM. Didn't work.

Comment: You sure the Receiver is listed correctly in the manifest; correct spelling, right folder, etc.?

Comment: @MikeM. Yes, it is correct. It reacts with actions received from my notification.

Comment: Are you setting a `PlaybackState` on the `MediaSession` anywhere?

Comment: @MikeM. No i didnt. Is'nt it just to send info to the `MediaSession`?

Comment: Depending on which Android version your compiling and testing against, setting the `PlaybackState` might be necessary for the Media Buttons to function, apparently.

Comment: @MikeM. I've fixed it with your help and some other links.
Please take a look at my follow up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33655051/android-mediasession-does-not-react-to-headphones-double-click

Answer (score 0):

First I've made all the calls to `MediaSession` to run on ui thread then I've added this code from google training:

```
AudioManager am = mContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
...

// Start listening for button presses
am.registerMediaButtonEventReceiver(RemoteControlReceiver);
...

// Stop listening for button presses
am.unregisterMediaButtonEventReceiver(RemoteControlReceiver);
```

http://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/volume-playback.html#PlaybackControls

and i saw the callbacks defined in this SO answer:
[How to use the new MediaSession class to receive media button presses on Android 5.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28798116/how-to-use-the-new-mediasession-class-to-receive-media-button-presses-on-android)

BTW, It is catched on the `MediaSession.Callback` and not in the `BroadcastReceiver`.