# Android MediaSession does not react to headphones double click

Tags: android

This is a follow up question to this one: [Android MediaSession not reacting to headphones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33596223/android-mediasession-not-reacting-to-headphones/33654884#33654884)

And I used it like in this question: [How to use the new MediaSession class to receive media button presses on Android 5.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28798116/how-to-use-the-new-mediasession-class-to-receive-media-button-presses-on-android)

But I dont get onSkipToNext on double click on the headphones, it just does play+pause. However i do get it on a BT receiver that has a specific button for each action. It works with android native app, so its not a headphones issue.

I'm running on nexus 5 lollipop and my app minSdk is 16.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the following actions:

PlaybackState.ACTION_SKIP_TO_NEXT 
PlaybackState.ACTION_SKIP_TO_PREVIOUS

you need set these actions in your mediaSession.setPlayBackState

Wait but if it works otherwise then probably this is not the issue I would suggest overriding the MediaSession callback