# Android capture media button when screen is off

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to capture when the media button is pressed while my screen is off. First I use `getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);` to keep my activity up over the lock screen and `PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK` (I know this drains the battery but this is will only be on for a short time). Then to listen for the media button I override `public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)` and use `if(keycode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK)`. The problem is this doesn't work if the screen is off.

I've seen a couple of people use BroadcastReceiver to capture the media button will that work if my screen is off?

If it won't work is there any way I can capture that event while the screen is off?

If it will work how would I implement that? because I've tried following some example on here but I cannot get it to work even when the screen is on. If the BroadcastReceiver will work I can post what I have so far that's not working even when the screen is on.

UPDATE

I found a similar answer at [use new media session class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28798116/how-to-use-the-new-mediasession-class-to-receive-media-button-presses-on-android). I can capture when the media button is pressed (even when the screen is off) but I don't capture when the volume button is pressed (screen on or off). Here is what I implemented:

```
mediaSession = new MediaSession(getApplicationContext(), this.getLocalClassName());

if (mediaSession == null) {
    Log.e("TEST", "initMediaSession: mediaSession = null");
    return;
}

mediaSessionToken = mediaSession.getSessionToken();

myVolumeProvider = new VolumeProviderCompat(VolumeProviderCompat.VOLUME_CONTROL_RELATIVE, 1000, 0) {
    @Override
    public void onAdjustVolume(int direction) {
    Log.d("TEST", "onAdjustVolume called: ");

    }
};

mediaSession.setPlaybackToRemote((VolumeProvider) myVolumeProvider.getVolumeProvider());
mediaSession.setCallback(new MediaSession.Callback()
{
    public boolean onMediaButtonEvent(Intent mediaButtonIntent) {
    Log.d("TEST", "onMediaButtonEvent called: " + mediaButtonIntent);
    return false;
    }

    public void onPause() {
    Log.d("TEST", "onPause called (media button pressed)");
    super.onPause();
    }

    public void onPlay() {
    Log.d("TEST", "onPlay called (media button pressed)");
    super.onPlay();
    }

    public void onStop() {
    Log.d("TEST", "onStop called (media button pressed)");
    super.onStop();
    }

});

mediaSession.setFlags(MediaSession.FLAG_HANDLES_MEDIA_BUTTONS | MediaSession.FLAG_HANDLES_TRANSPORT_CONTROLS);

PlaybackState state = new PlaybackState.Builder()
    .setActions(PlaybackState.ACTION_PLAY)
    .setState(PlaybackState.STATE_STOPPED, PlaybackState.PLAYBACK_POSITION_UNKNOWN, 0)
    .build();

mediaSession.setPlaybackState(state);

mediaSession.setActive(true);
```

Comment: Have you tried to registrer a BroadcastReceiver with a service instead of your activity? Services are executed even when screen if off / application not in foreground.